# Gatsby project not loading Data when deployed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I am fairly new to gatsby and I have a header component in my gatsby project that uses the useStaticQuery hook and works fine on local. However, when I deployed the gatsby project using GitHub gh-pages, the header didn't render any links and there was no error in the console too. After making my research,  I saw that a number of people have had thesame issue caused by the useStaticQuery hook and they advised to use the StaticQuery component instead of the useStaticQuery hook. I am trying to refactor my code to use the StaticQuery component  however I am not sure how I would extract data  from the StaticQuery component to use in a useEffect hook

so if I have something like this

```js
import { graphql, Link, StaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import React from "react"
import { NavbarBrand } from "reactstrap"

export default () => {

  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            appModules
          }
        }
      }
    `}
      render={data => (
    <header>
      <NavbarBrand href="/">
        <img className="m-0" src="/doc/images/img" alt={data.site.siteMetadata.title} />
      </NavbarBrand>
      <div>
        {data.site.siteMetadata.appModules.map((appModule, index) => (
          <Link key={index} to={`/${appModule}`}>
            {appModule} 
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </header>
      )}
      />
  )
}
```

and i need to use data.site.siteMetadata.appModules in a useEffect like this

```js
import { graphql, Link, StaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import React, {useEffect} from "react"
import { NavbarBrand } from "reactstrap"

export default () => {

    useEffect(() => {
    
      console.log(data.site.siteMetadata.appModules)
    
    }, [])

  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            appModules
          }
        }
      }
    `}
      render={data => (
    <header>
      <NavbarBrand href="/">
        <img className="m-0" src="/doc/images/img" alt={data.site.siteMetadata.title} />
      </NavbarBrand>
      <div>
        {data.site.siteMetadata.appModules.map((appModule, index) => (
          <Link key={index} to={`/${appModule}`}>
            {appModule} 
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </header>
      )}
      />
  )
}
```

how would i extract the data.site.siteMetadata.appModules so i can use it in a useEffect just like the way useStaticQuery gives us that flexibility

```js
const allMenuQuery = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query MyQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
          appModules
        }
      }
      allMarkdownRemark(
        sort: { fields: frontmatter___submenuOrder, order: ASC }
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              menu
              menuOrder
              submenu
              submenuOrder
              module
            }
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  const { appModules } = allMenuQuery.site.siteMetadata
  // debugger
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(appModules)
  }, [])
```

or if you know how I can make the useStaticQuery hook work in the deployed gatsby app without refactoring my code to the StaticQuery component I would really appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `useEffect` because your data is already inside the `render`'s function scope. You don't need it either in `allMenuQuery` (the snippet with `useStaticQuery`) because the data is statically analyzed, it doesn't need to be dependent on the DOM to be rendered.

This should work:

```
import { graphql, Link, StaticQuery } from "gatsby";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { NavbarBrand } from "reactstrap";

export default () => {
  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query {
          site {
            siteMetadata {
              title
              appModules
            }
          }
        }
      `}
      render={(data) => {
        console.log("your app modules", data.site.siteMetadata.appModules);
        return (
          <header>
            <NavbarBrand href="/">
              <img
                className="m-0"
                src="/doc/images/img"
                alt={data.site.siteMetadata.title}
              />
            </NavbarBrand>
            <div>
              {data.site.siteMetadata.appModules.map((appModule, index) => (
                <Link key={index} to={`/${appModule}`}>
                  {appModule}
                </Link>
              ))}
            </div>
          </header>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Keep in mind that both approaches (`staticQuery` and `useStaticQuery`) are different ways of triggering **static** queries. You don't need to rely on the DOM (like the empty deps, `[]`) does. Both approaches should work.